# sprintf expects argument of type char * - but type IS char

Tags: command, printf, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

Thats code:

```
void bleAdvData(char *advData, uint8_t size){

char command[18+size];
uint8_t commandUint[18+size];

sprintf(command, "AT+BLEADVDATA=\"%s\"\r\n", *advData);
```

Warning in sprintf line:

```
Argument %s expects argument of type "char *", but argument 3 has type int
```

Why?

And what i have to do:
I want to trasfer a string(advData) wtich the length of "size" into a function for get a string command like:

```
AT+BLEADVDATA="advData"\r\n
```

Comment: you have it as `*(*char)`

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `advData` is defined as `char *` in the argument list. This is a pointer to an address where character data is stored. However, in your `sprintf()` you use `*advData`, ie the actual place where `advData` points to, not the address itself.

Take the `*` off in the `sprintf()`, and all should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: `char *advData` on the first line makes `advData` a `char *`.

But then you added an asterisk to `advData` so you have `* (char *advData)`.

So you want this:

```
 sprintf(command, "AT+BLEADVDATA=\"%s\"\r\n", advData);
```

---

That extra asterisk "dereferences" the `advData` so you're now trying to pass in the first character of the string

`sprintf` then complains since that's not a valid string. If you ran this it'd either crash or on the ESP32 give you gibberish.

I recommend using the Warnings as Errors option on the ESP32. It's very rare that a warning won't be meaningful, and the ESP32 doesn't crash as easily as  a program running on a modern PC OS.

That leads to really hard to find bugs where stuff randomly works or crashes with no clear pattern.